# MySQL: Using the result from one query as input to another

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, resultset

I have a massive database where a certain query is taking around 7 seconds to return a result because each query does several counts among other computations.  To speed it up, I'd like to make a new lookup table that already has these counts computed and stored.

I know I could easily write a program to fill the table, but I'd like to know if there is a way to generate the same result set **without** external processing.

Take for example, the result set from:

`SELECT DISTINCT city, state FROM lkp_city_state AS locations;`

Now, for each of these city/state combinations, I'd like to count the number of Ferarris and Lamborghinis in them.  Something along the lines of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_ferarris FROM cars WHERE manufacturer = 'ferarri' AND city = locations.city AND state = locations.state
    JOIN
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_lambos FROM cars WHERE manufacturer = 'lamborghini' AND city = locations.city AND state = locations.state`
```

The ideal result set columns would be something like:

`city | state | num_ferarris | num_lambos`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join directly to your list in one query

```
SELECT 
      locations.city,
      locations.state,
      cars.manufacturer,
      COUNT(*)
   FROM cars 
      JOIN lkp_city_state AS locations;
         on cars.city = locations.city
        and cars.state = locations.state
   WHERE 
         cars.manufacturer = 'ferarri' 
      OR cars.manufacturer = 'lamborghini'
   GROUP BY
      locations.city,
      locations.state,
      cars.manufacturer
```

If you want it in a single row, you could pivot the results

```
SELECT 
      locations.city,
      locations.state,
      sum( case when cars.manufacturer = 'ferarri' then 1 else 0 end ) as Num_Ferarri,
      sum( case when cars.manufacturer = 'lamborghini' then 1 else 0 end ) as Num_Lambos
   FROM cars 
      JOIN lkp_city_state AS locations;
         on cars.city = locations.city
        and cars.state = locations.state
   WHERE 
         cars.manufacturer = 'ferarri' 
      OR cars.manufacturer = 'lamborghini';
       GROUP BY
          locations.city,
          locations.state,
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using `indexes`. I did not use them in the past but recently confirmed they do incredible good job to accelerate queries.

Secondly, I think something like this could work:

```
SELECT * FROM
(    SELECT 
      c.city, c.state, COUNT(*) as num_lambo
    FROM cars AS c
    LEFT JOIN locations
      ON  locations.city = c.city AND locations.state = c.state
    WHERE manufacturer = 'lambo' )A

JOIN

(    SELECT 
      c.city, c.state, COUNT(*) as num_ferr
    FROM cars AS c
    LEFT JOIN locations
      ON  locations.city = c.city AND locations.state = c.state
    WHERE manufacturer = 'ferrari' )B
```

[SQL Fiddle testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77cda/17)